# MicrosoftSqlServerCe.Client not in GAC

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have successfully built a desktop application and published it with Visual Studio. The prerequisites are .Net Framework 40 and SQL Server CE. When I run the installer on a machine with none of these, it runs and installs both prerequisites well. But when it comes to installing the application itself, I get a pop up titled

> SYSTEM UPDATE REQUIRED
>   Unable to install or run the application. The application requires
>   that assembly MicrosoftSqlServerCe.Client version 4.0.0.0 be installed
>   in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first

I thought the SQL Server Compact was supposed to take care of that automatically. What should I do please help. I don't want to have users of the application do complicated stuff in order to get the app to work. Help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a reference somewhere to Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client - that should be changed to System.Data.SqlServerCe (the Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client dll is a design time only component)

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked a charm.I actually had both references Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client was reference automatically when I created the project so I thought it was somehow needed. Thank you.

Comment: I'd like to add an example from my project. I'm developing WPF enterprise application and we was need to have working application without installed SqlServerCe on the machine. When I changed in `App.config` version from 0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0 to 4.0.0.0-4.0.0.1 everything works for me. Here's full block of code <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>