# Missing SqlServerCe Reference in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Why doesn't System.Data.SqlServerCe show up under references in Visual Studio?

I have SQL Compact 3.5 and 4.0 installed, both 32 and 64 bit.

I have also tried reinstalling VS 2010 and VS 2012, neither can find the reference.

I can add this reference manually but then things mess up because it has trouble finding sqlceme35.dll, which can't be added as a .NET reference.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ7u9.png

Comment: Have you installed the SQL Server CE SDK?

Comment: See this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300537/microsoftsqlserverce-client-not-in-gac

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493674/cannot-find-namespace-system-data-sqlserverce